# Link & Expose Docker Container Simultaniously

Tags: docker

Does the following command link two containers **and also** expose the port on my network?..

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --link my-postgres:postgres danwahlin/aspnetcore
```

I'm watching Dav Wahlin's course on Docker and this one command is blowing my mind.  Does this mean that port 5000 will be accessible from my network AND linked between the two containers?  If so, then the link isn't essential to communicate between the containers since they *could* just use the IP and port in a config file.  Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're confusing "legacy linking" with "container networks".  Creating a **link**, as your example shows, creates an entry in the containers `hosts` file so they can resolve each other by name.

In the example above, you created an **alias** of "postgres" to the "my-postgres" container.  Think **name resolution** here.  This does nothing to isolate the network stack.

Next you have the `--port` or `-p` switch which exposes a container port to the network.  Here you are exposing port 5000.  Without this switch you would not expose anything and, therefore, would not receive any incoming calls.

Should you want to **isolate** containers you could do so using a "bridge network" like so:

```
docker network create --driver bridge mynetwork
```

Once the network is created, only containers added to the network will communicate with each other.  For example:

```
docker run -d --net=mynetwork --name postgres postgres:latest
docker run -d --net=mynetwork --name node node:latest
```